# How to determine the period of these matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory, discrete-mathematics

I have these three matrices.

$a=\left(\begin{matrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{matrix}\right)$, $b=\left(\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 1
\end{matrix}\right)$, $c=\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & -1 \\
0 & 1
\end{matrix}\right)$

They belong to $GL_2(\Bbb Q)$. I know the meaning of the period of an element but I don't understand how to verify if these matrices are periodical and eventually how to calculate their period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nice approach here is to compute the minimal polynomial (which in this case coincides with the characteristic polynomial) of each matrix.  Note that a polynomial $p$ will satisfy $p(M) = 0$ if and only if the minimal polynomial $m(x)$ of $M$ divides $p$.

In this case, we calculate minimal polynomials
$$
m_a(x) = x^2 + 1\\
m_b(x) = x^2 - x + 1\\
m_c(x) = x^2 - 2x + 1
$$
$m_a$ and $m_b$ each divide a polynomial of the form $p(x) = x^n - 1$ for some $n$. $m_c$ divides no such polynomial since such a $p(x)$ has no repeated roots over $\Bbb C$, but $m_c$ does.

---

Alternative approach: trial and error (calculating successive powers) reveals that $a^4 = I$ and $a^6 = I$ (we might expect that this holds for $a$ if we recognize that it is a rotation matrix).  However, we find that
$$
c^n = \pmatrix{1&-1\\0&1}^n = \left(\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1} + \pmatrix{0&-1\\0&0}\right)^n = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&1} + n \pmatrix{0&-1\\0&0}\\
= \pmatrix{1&-n\\0&1}
$$
which makes it clear that if $n > 0$, $c^n$ cannot be the identity matrix.

Comment: what could be an alternative approach?

Comment: @Jack see my latest edit

Comment: Thanks for the answer. could the information that $c=a*b$ be used to prove that I cannot obtain the identity matrix with any powers?

Comment: @Jack I don't see any way to do so.  There are certainly examples where $a,b,$ and $ab$ all have finite order